# Transaction sent from wrong Ledger account in Metamask

Tags: metamask, ledger-nano-s

I use two ETH accounts on my Ledger - account [1] and [2]. When submitting a contract or transfering ETH on the mainnet from account [2] via Metamask it still sends from [1].

**To Reproduce**

1. Click on 'Connect Hardware Wallet', select 'Ledger' and click 'connect'
2. Choose 'Ledger Live' as HDPath and select Ledger account [2] and click on 'Unlock'
3. Deploy contract on Remix/transfer ETH  with this account
4. Transaction history in Metamask shows 'From' address to be account [2], but in Etherscan it is obivious, that [1] has been used.

**Expected behavior**

Use selected account to send ETH.

**Browser details**

- OS: Windows 10
- Ledger Nano S, Firmware version 1.6.0
- Chrome Version 79.0.3945.117 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- MetaMask Version 7.7.2

I already opened a [bug report on the Metamask GitHub page](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/7845), but maybe it's my mistake?